# why <img> tag loadstart event not trigger ? Is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vuejs with Element UI, I want to show loading indicator when  begin load image from src attr, hide loading indicator when `load` event(img loaded) trigger.

The `load` event works well, but `loadstart` never fire.

Here is snippet:

```
<div v-loading="imgLoading">
  <img
    :src="imgOfSelectedColor"
    @loadstart="showImgLoading"
    @load="hideImgLoading"
    @error="hideImgLoading"
    @abort="hideImgLoading"
  >
</div>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgLoading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showImgLoading() {
      this.imgLoading = true;
    },
    hideImgLoading() {
      this.imgLoading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: loadstart only applies to video and audio tags, it is not a valid event for img tags. See supported tags section https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadstart.asp

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Is there an alternative for img ?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's not true. ProgressEvents apply to a bunch of APIs, they were even originally implemented for XHR objects. And HTMLImageElement should fire the `loadstart` event as [the 11th step of *updating-the-image-data* algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#updating-the-image-data). Now, only Firefox among common browsers implemented this part of the specs, so *ifeng*, which browser did you test this from?

Comment: @Kaiido `Chrome 73.0.3683.103 x64`.

Comment: Will be hard (if not impossible) to correctly polyfill this. I guess the best is to make your voice so that [this 4 yrs old bug-report finally get treated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458851).

Comment: @Kaiido Understood, thank you.